# Prove that a subspace from row space and another from row echelon form space are equal.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to prove this:

Let $A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix with components in $\mathbb{R}$. Then, we can consider each row as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We can also consider the subspace $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ generated from this $m$ vectors. Then, with the matrix $B$, being the row echelon form of the matrix $A$, we can consider the subspace $W$ generated by the $m$ vectors given by the rows of $B$.

Prove that $U=W$.

Prove that the vectors given by the non-null rows of $B$ are linearly independent.

I don't really know where or how to start.
(Sorry if the text is a bit cluncky, I couldn't find it in english.)

Comment: You were trying to prove it, so where did you stumble?

Comment: When getting the REF of a matrix, we take some lines (- "vectors") and do one of three things on them (elementary operations) , so - the new line is a linear combination of the rows. For the second question, try showing that the REF must contain a different amount of leading zero at each row

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Well, I don't really know how to start. To be frank, I don't even know how to prove that two spaces (or subespaces) are equal.

Comment: @WATER Thank you very much. I'll try to go from there.